# Warning: str_repeat(): Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0

Tags: php

I used this a while back to grab images from something but since I just tried using it again it is giving me this error:

> Warning: str_repeat(): Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\resource_update.php on line 121

This is the function for what its referring to so if anyone could help that would be great:

```
function consoleLogProgressBar($current, $size, $unit = "kb")
{
$length = (int)(($current/$size)*100);
$str = sprintf("\r[%-100s] %3d%% (%2d/%2d%s)", str_repeat("=", $length).($length==100?"":">"), $length, ($current/($unit=="kb"?1024:1)), $size/($unit=="kb"?1024:1), " ".$unit);
consoleLog($str, true);
}
```

Comment: What parameters are you passing to `consoleLogProgressBar()`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `$length` is returning a negative number? You could troubleshoot as follows:

```
$length = (int)(($current/$size)*100);
var_dump($length);
exit;
```

If that is in fact the case, then you could wrap it in the `abs()` function which will always return an absolute value:

```
$length = (int) abs(($current/$size)*100);
```

Of course, that is an ugly hack and doesn't solve the real issue. Either way, the first step is determine why `$length` isn't what you expect it to be.